# Zoom takes 90% cpu and cpu overheats and shutdown system

Tags: shutdown, cpu, overheat

Here is my system config:

```
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            USER@MYSYSTEM
      eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee         ------------------ 
    eeeee  eeeeeeeeeeee   eeeee       OS: elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir x86_64 
  eeee   eeeee       eee     eeee     Host: Latitude 3420 
 eeee   eeee          eee     eeee    Kernel: 5.15.0-83-generic 
eee    eee            eee       eee   Uptime: 44 mins 
eee   eee            eee        eee   Packages: 2508 (dpkg), 13 (flatpack) 
ee    eee           eeee       eeee   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
ee    eee         eeeee      eeeeee   Resolution: 2560x1080 
ee    eee       eeeee      eeeee ee   DE: Pantheon 
eee   eeee   eeeeee      eeeee  eee   WM: Mutter(Gala) 
eee    eeeeeeeeee     eeeeee    eee   Theme: io.elementary.stylesheet.lime [GTK3] 
 eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee    eeeee    Icons: elementary [GTK3] 
  eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeee      eeee     Terminal: io.elementary.t 
    eeeee                 eeeee       CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 4.700GHz 
      eeeeeee         eeeeeee         GPU: Intel Device 9a49 
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            Memory: 5092MiB / 64037MiB
```

Every time in a zoom meeting when someone shares screen, zoom starts taking 90% of the cpu and soon the CPU temperature shoots up to the critical level where the system shuts down. Zoom crashing the system is still a problem, is there a work around for this?